# Is it safe to use a mouldy case for an electric guitar?

Tags: electric-guitar, maintenance

My guitar hard case (Stagg Vintage-style series gold tweed deluxe hardshell case for electric guitar)  has changed color to green and dark red on the some parts of the outside, and it seems that the cause may be related to water that seeps through the wall. The water seems to dampen the case but I'm not quite sure. The inside of the case is in good condition. Is it still safe to use the hard case?

Comment: If the case is growing mould, not only does it need drying, it needs decontaminating, as does the rest of the room. You're *breathing* that. Start by getting the wall fixed, then invest in a dehumidifier… or move out.

Comment: There’s a product called “Concrobium Mold Control” (at least in the US). It’s a spray that has minerals dissolved in water. When you spray it on mold, it is absorbed by the mold and then the minerals precipitate out and expand, killing the mold. It is effective at killing existing mold and preventing that mold from producing unhealthy spores. It does not prevent new mold, and it does not remove mold stains. It is safe for fabrics and wood in the sense that it won’t damage them beyond the damage already suffered from wetness. (1/2)

Comment: I suggest first figuring out how to stop the area from getting wet. Then throw away anything that has mold on it that you can bear to part with. Then get some of this mold killing spray and spray it on everything that has mold stains that you can’t or don’t want to throw away every day for a week. Then either consider finding a new place to live or research professional mold abatement. You don’t want to live any longer than you have to in a place that ever had mold unless it’s been professionally removed. Also throw away this guitar case unless you really can’t bear to. (2/2)

Comment: You might also post on the home improvement stack about mold in general and whether wood and fabrics can be made safe after mold has grown on them.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, but only after it's had a thorough drying out. What wall is the water seeping through? And a room like that is not the place to put the case, with/out guitar! Under a bed could work, or put the whole lot in a sealed plastic sack if it *must* go into that room.

Comment: Just drying out doesn’t kill many molds. They can live on normal relative humidity in the room and keep emitting unhealthy spores

Comment: @ToddWilcox - in that case, the case needs a good brush down (and we all wear masks anyway, now!) and a spray with a disinfectant, then another dry. Or would you suggest otherwise? Too good to throw away, I think.

Comment: I put my recommendations in comments on the question. Sadly I’ve dealt with lots of mold in my life and it’s hard to fully kill. Bleach doesn’t necessarily do it. On non-porous surfaces you can essentially scrub it off, but on anything porous you have to kill it somehow or it’s always there. And of course keeping it from coming back can be hard depending on how the moisture is getting to the affected area.

Comment: @ToddWilcox - sorry, completely missed your other comments! They look like a good answer, rather than  comments.